# How do I read digital input on atmega series and use it in such code?

Tags: microcontroller, c, atmega, atmel

if (pin1 of port c high)
{preform a task

considering that

1. pin 5 and 6 are connected to an rtc via i2c and pin 0-3 is an input from lm35 (which I was able to write a code for) :p
2. using atmega8
3. I've set the ddrc with the following command > ddrc=ddrc & 0xf0

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Have you looked at any example code?

Comment: i scanned through the whole Mazdi Ali's book...could have done the same thing in assembly...c is not well explained there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one's biting so I'll take it. However, this concept is documented pretty thoroughly online. Also, reading the datasheet of the ATmega8 in the future will help your understanding greatly of the MCU in general. Digikey is a great resource for datasheets, I easily found the one for the ATmega8 here:

[ATmega8 Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf)

Use the PINx register to read the pins from port "x". DDRx sets the pin direction (0 is read, 1 is output).

For example, to read pin PA5, setup with DDRA:

```
DDRA &= 0xDF;        //Mask 0xDF onto DDRA if you don't want to screw up the rest of the bits
                    //0xDF = 0b11011111
```

There's a few techniques here, but the PINA is where you want to read from. If I have a pullup resistor attached to my PA5, then LOW if button press (or whatever your application is)

```
if(0x00 == (PINA & (1 <<  PA5))){
  /*Pin LOW, execute code*/   
}
```

Basically you're ANDing PINA with 0x20. If the button is pressed, PINA will be: 0bXX0XXXXX (X's for some bits because it doesn't matter what they are), so you can see PA5 is 0. This ANDed with 0x20 makes 0x00, hence the check.

Comment: that means this will be correct                                if(0x08 == (PINC & 0x08)){//do stuff if pin3,is high it will do stuff}

Comment: @SurajGrewal you don't even need the '==', ```if (PINC & 0x08) {//Do stuff if high}``` and ```if (!(PINC & 0x08)) {//Do stuff if low}``` will work. But generally we use the ```(1<<Pxn)``` notation rather than a literal value as it is easier to read - the compile will automatically replace the bit shift by a constant so the compiled code *exactly* the same.